# Setting up a resource lock with converting into map

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting the following error during the apply process. It's always said that lock_level is not part of the variable.

**variable.tf **

```
variable "private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint" {
  type = map(object({
    resource_group_name       = string
    name                      = string
    virtual_network_link_name = string
    lock_level                = optional(string)
  }))
  default     = {}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this-private_dns_zone" {
  for_each = {for key,value in var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint : key => value if coalesce(var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"}
  name = coalesce(data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.value].name, "lock-${data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.value].name}")
  scope = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.value].id
  lock_level = var.lock.kind
}
```

**Error**

```
│ Error: Missing map element
│
│   on ../../main.tf line 639, in resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this-private_dns_zone":
│  639:   for_each = {for key,value in var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint : key => value if coalesce(var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint is map of object with 3 elements
│
│ This map does not have an element with the key "lock_level".
```

Comment: the issue is because you're trying to access the lock_level attribute from the private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint variable. Try  using for_each = {for key,value in var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint : key => value if coalesce(value.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"}
instead of 


for_each = {for key,value in var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint : key => value if coalesce(var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"}

Comment: i get this error on it..  ' Error: Invalid index
│
│   on ../../main.tf line 640, in resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this-private_dns_zone":
│  640:   name = coalesce(data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.value].name, "lock-${data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.value].name}")
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint is object with 3 attributes
│     │ each.value is object with 4 attributes
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: string required.'

Comment: change your name attribute to name = coalesce(data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.key].name, "lock-${data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.key].name}")

because  data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint becomes a map of DNS zones indexed by the keys of var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to set up a resource lock by converting it into a map and could provision the requirement successfully.

The error you have seen is because you are trying to access the `lock_level` attribute from the `private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint` variable.

In the mentioned `for_each` loop. You're repeating over the key and value of each element in the map `private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint`. If you want to access the `lock_level` attribute of each object inside that map.

And also the error mentioned in the comment was because you're trying to index `data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint` with `each.value`, but `data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint` is an object, not a list or map, so you can't index it in that way.

I took the configuration for demo purposes to show how to call the variables of your requirement.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint" {
  type = map(object({
    resource_group_name       = string
    name                      = string
    virtual_network_link_name = string
    lock_level                = optional(string)
  }))
  default = {}
}

variable "lock_kind" {
  description = "Specifies the Level to be used for this Lock."
  type        = string
  default     = "None"
}
```

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "public_endpoint" {
  for_each = var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint

  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this-private_dns_zone" {
  for_each = {for key,value in var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint : key => value if coalesce(value.lock_level, var.lock_kind) != "None"}

  name       = coalesce(data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.key].name, "lock-${data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.key].name}")
  scope      = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.public_endpoint[each.key].id
  lock_level = var.lock_kind
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

This configuration will help in overcoming the blocker mentioned in the query.

Comment: Can we add another condition to same for_each like, proceed only if we have values in "var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint" ?

Comment: Yes, you can add additional conditions to the for_each loop to ensure that you only iterate over entries when var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint has values

Comment: │ Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
│
│   on ../../main.tf line 632, in resource "azurerm_management_lock" "this-private_endpoints":
│  632:   for_each = {for key,value in local.private_endpoints : key => value if coalesce(var.private_endpoints.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.private_endpoints is null
│
│ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
╵

Comment: added following : - for_each = local.private_endpoints != null && local.private_endpoints != {} ? {for key,value in local.private_endpoints : key => value if coalesce(var.private_endpoints.lock_level, var.lock.kind) != "None"} : {}